# I Must add two Attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create an attribute 'score' and 'learn' in my code.
I am getting these error:

> AttributeError: 'HumanPlayer' object has no attribute 'score' and
>   'learn'.

See some parts of the codes below:

```
#Create random player class
class RandomPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        Player.__init__(self)

    def move(self):

        self.move = RandomPlayer
        #use imported random function
        RandomPlayer = random.randint(1,3) 

        #Computer choice is either rock, paper, or scissors 
        if RandomPlayerMove == ("Rock"): 
            print("The computer choses ROCK") 
        elif RandomPlayerMove == ("Paper"): 
            print("The computer choses PAPER") 
        else: 
            print("The computer choses SCISSORS") 

        #return value 
        return RandomPlayer 



#Create human player class        
class HumanPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        Player.__init__(self)

    def move(self):
        while True:
            HumanPlayer = input("'Rock', 'Paper', or 'Scissors' ")
        #Detect invalid entry
            if HumanPlayer.lower() not in moves:
                print('Please choose Paper, Rock or Scissors: ')
            else:
                break
        return HumanPlayer



class Game:

    def __init__(self, HumanPlayer, RandomPlayer):
        self.player1 = HumanPlayer
        self.player2 = RandomPlayer
        self.player1_score = 0
        self.player2_score = 0

    def play_round(self):

        move1 = self.player1.move()
        move2 = self.player2.move()
        print(f"Player 1: {move1}  Player 2: {move2}")
        self.player1.learn(move1, move2)
        self.player2.learn(move2, move1)

        if (move1 == move2):
            print("it's a tie!")

        elif beats(move1, move2) is True:
                self.player1_score += 1
        elif beats(move2, move1) is True:
                self.player2_score += 1

        print("It's Tie, Play again!")
        print(f"Scores, HumanPlayer: {self.player1.score} RandomPlayer: {self.player2.score}")
        print("Game over!")
```

Comment: In which part did you get the error?  And do you really have there two attributes in that class?

Comment: Hi, for these two parts play_round:  self.player1.learn(move1, move2) and self.player1_score += 1.  Python says humanplayer and Randomplayer object do not have these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is due to a typo. Rather than `self.player1.score` in your next to last `print` statement, you probably want `self.player1_score`, since that's an attribute you've defined in `__init__`. Similarly, you probably want `self.player2_score` instead of `self.player2.score` later in the same format string.

While it doesn't appear to be the cause of your current issues, there is another suggestion I'd like to make: Avoid using the same name for different things. You have a whole bunch of places where you're using the same name for both an instance and a class. For instance, your `Game` class takes arguments named `HumanPlayer` and `RandomPlayer`, which hide the classes with those names. You're also using your class names as variable names in each of your `move` methods. This is going to make bug fixing a nightmare! Use unique names. Python convention is to use `CapitalizedNames` for classes, `lowercase_names_with_underscores` for most other variables (including function and method names), and `ALL_CAPS` for constants (in the rare cases you need them), but you *can* use your own style if you prefer (just be consistent!).

Comment: thank you @Blckknght. I have updated the code as per your advise and it works fine, I am more advanced in the game as before. now, it does play the game, but, at the end of the game it throws the same error message:                                                                                                            AttributeError: 'HumanPlayer' object has no attribute 'learn'

Comment: That second issue is due to your code that calls `self.player1.learn(move1, move2)` and `self.player2.learn(move2, move1)`. You haven't written any corresponding methods, so that gives you an exception. Did you intend to write those methods, but just haven't gotten around to it yet?

Comment: Hi Blckknght, I haven't gotten around it yet.